# Is there a way to make the autocompletion from "require"-ing a file apply to multiple files in the same folder in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

So I have two JavaScript files in the same folder in Visual Studio. I want to get access to autocompletion/suggestions for function calls and variables in both files, but only have a single `require()`. When you include both in an HTML script tag, it's functionally going to work only having it require the file once, but I want to be able to have VSCode recognize that.

For example. Here's file 1:

```
let foo = require("foo")

foo.sendMessage()
foo.sendMassage()
foo.sendMossage()
```

And file 2:

```
foo.send
```

I want VSCode to bring up that suggestion list of available function calls and variables that start with `send`.

I've found extensions that do this for NodeJS files, but is there a way or already existing extension, or is it even possible, that does this for other JS classes in files inside the same project/folder?

Comment: you do `require`s in a script for the web? how? I thought it was only for nodeJS.

Comment: you could write [a declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html). But how would this even work at runtime? How does a NodeJS script use things from another script without a `require`?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming a Windows environment:

```
ctrl + space
```

will trigger suggestions. Suggestions triggered without preceding characters will include almost all available importable items in your project. When you pick the sendMessage from the other file it will actually automatically add the import to the top of the file.
[image: Trigger suggestions]

In your situation type send, then trigger suggestion and you'll see your other sendMessage function.

Plenty of other helpful shortcuts here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

For other envs:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually in a Linux environment sadly but I'll still give these links a look. Also I should say this doesn't really solve my problem. I don't need a way to trigger suggestions, I need a way to make it pull suggestions from a different file without including/requiring/importing it

Comment: See edit. VScode does exactly what your asking. See updated answer. Keyboard shortcut is the same in Linux.